# ASP.NET - C# - Handling Redundant? IOException on File.WriteAllText

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, io

```
private static string directory = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"LOGS\");
private static string fileName = "log.log"
public static void SaveFile()
{
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(directory, fileName), "MyText");
}
```

For some reason whenever I call the above SaveFile method, File.WriteAllText throws an error stating the file is being used by another process (which I don't know what nor do I think it actually is) and Visual Studio breaks on that exception.

However, if I tell Visual Studio to continue on with the code, the file is written to perfectly fine and everything executes normally. This is strange in and of itself, but I have tried wrapping the File.WriteAllText in a *try/catch* block just to ignore the error, but this causes errors further up the stack chain so that idea does not work.

I have also tried a "wait-until-file-is-available" closure to handle file not being available, but that just causes an infinite loop because the file never becomes available? (see below for code)

```
private static string directory = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"LOGS\");
private static string fileName = "log.log"

public static void SaveFile()
{
    bool fileSaved = false;
    while (!fileSaved)
    {
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(directory, fileName), "MyText");
            fileSaved = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            fileSaved = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This entire method is part of handling the logging of a critical / fatal error in an ASP.NET/C# website. I have tried some stranger solutions including manually calling GarbageCollector, calling the method via separate Thread, using Directory/FileStream/StreamWriter, etc. all without success.

Is there a more appropriate way to handle this error or a way that it is forcefully ignored *JUST* for this one line / File.WriteAllText call?

Comment: given that it's a log, would appending the text work?

Comment: @chris-crush-code I tried that as well and it still produces the same error. At any rate, appending is not really an option since the log will live on a server when I deploy the site and get e-mailed to me when there is an error and then the next time there is an error the log gets overwritten with the new error information and e-mailed again. This keeps the log file small and manageable and prevents the server from getting filled up with logs.

Comment: A guess would be during debugging a file handle got left open on that file.  Did you try rebooting your machine and running the code once through to see if it works at that point?

Comment: @chris-crush-code Yes. I have restarted Visual Studio 3 times and my PC 4 times to see if there was something that could be interfering with the file. No luck there either.

Comment: Okay, 1 more idea here.  Try a folder outside of your source code (something like C:\temp\ instead of AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.  I'm wondering if maybe source control has the file locked or just visual studio itself is doing something with files within the app's directory.

Comment: @chris-crush-code same result using both temp & Desktop folders.

Comment: I made a console application with exactly your code and had no problem executing it.  I'm thinking it must be that some other threads within the app are interacting with the file.  An alternative would be to use something like NLog and set up the email option on it since that's what you're after anyways.  Realistically you could simply set up email with the .Net Mail namespace and bypass the entire file writing task - whatever was going in the file just stick in the body of the email.

Comment: @chris-crush-code The email that is sent is done that way too (i.e. the basic error information is dumped into the message), but the formatting is "destroyed" when the log's content is put into the email message. So much so that it becomes a task in an of itself to read the dump log. There is a lot of additional information that it is needed / would be nice to have when errors occur. This is an ASP.NET site, so might that cause an issue? I am hooking into the Application_Error method to call my debug methods (of which SaveLog is one).

Comment: Ah, you didn't say that.  I think that's the crux of your issue.  It's too long for a comment, I'll ad an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

> An error handler that is defined in the Global.asax file will only
>   catch errors that occur during processing of requests by the ASP.NET
>   runtime. For example, it will catch the error if a user requests an
>   .aspx file that does not occur in your application. However, it does
>   not catch the error if a user requests a nonexistent .htm file. For
>   non-ASP.NET errors, you can create a custom handler in Internet
>   Information Services (IIS). The custom handler will also not be called
>   for server-level errors. You cannot directly output error information
>   for requests from the Global.asax file; you must transfer control to
>   another page, typically a Web Forms page. When transferring control to
>   another page, use Transfer method. This preserves the current context
>   so that you can get error information from the GetLastError method.
>   After handling an error, you must clear it by calling the ClearError
>   method of the Server object (HttpServerUtility class).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx

To see if this is causing your error, in the actual code behind or controller put in a call to saveFile() and see if that throws the error.  Based on the quote above, it sounds like you can't do much from the global.asax.

Comment: I kind of figured out my issue...well at least found the real issue. The thread that the code was executing doubled up on itself. App_Error catches an error (which I try/catch'ed brilliantly) and in the process of logging the error got another critical error and called itself again while the first error was still trying to log itself / save itself. This at least points me in the right direction. Thanks